# "Promoting Certain Keywords" petition for migration instead of close

Tags: discussion

The question [Promoting Certain Keywords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29653/promoting-certain-keywords) cannot be answered by what it was tagged as an exact duplicate of. Instead, it should be migrated to WordPress SO, as the question is very specific to a set of global keywords for each page in addition to a set of local keywords.

Comment: Wordpress would just close the question and flame us for the migration, if I thought it was a technique question I would have answered but he does say "Site is for writers and bloggers so i want to promote some specific keywords like "online writing community" so that if some one search for such words on Google, search engine can place my site on some top results." Which led me to the conclusion it was a how to hack google results question.

Comment: Taking from that quote, it seems that the writer and bloggers are going to be his users (Or a select number of people). He simply wants to add global, static keywords in addition to the dynamic ones that his users / recruited writers can add. As he said in the beginning of the question, he is new to SEO - therefore he doesn't know how to phrase the question using the correct terminology to prevent such assumptions.

Comment: I get it, but it's still a question about how to make his site rank better which is why it got closed as a dupe. If you or he want to submit your question (which is a better question by the way) then go ahead, I'll certainly have a bash at an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is a tool for creating websites. I don't see anything in the question that would mean that you need to know about the underlying tool for this site in order to answer it.

Comment: As I said in my question; techniques to add keywords to your website isn't @Umesh Awasthi's question. It's clear he knows **how** to add keywords and what they are for. He's simply wondering how to add a set of static keywords for each page in addition to the dynamic ones. In either case the question doesn't belong here, atleast let WordPress SO try to give him the information he needs instead of the pre-packaged answer that doesn't give him anything useful for his situation.

Comment: He wants the static keywords to help his ranking. I think two of the things that would do that are creating relevant content using those words, which is a writing skill, and getting external sites to link to his using those keywords, which is a PR skill. Recreating the question in Wordpress SO is another option.

Comment: Yes, his question is in the realm of SEO, but there are plenty of questions that are similarly SEO-oriented that do not get closed, rather migrated or even answered. Regardless, the 'exact duplicate' question that is referenced does **not** answer his question, therefore not a duplicate. Recreating the question is unnecessary... I believed that the goal of SE is to provide a core of information, reopening the question then migrating it to WordPress is the best solution.